# Location of "Connect to Server..." mount

Tags: mountpoint, shared-folders

If I mount a Windows share using the "Places>Connect to Server..." option where is it mounted and is it always mounted at the same place?

I need to know the path so I can access it from the Terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should found it under `~/.gvfs`.

For more information see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS)

Answer (score 3):

On My 14.04 Desktop:

```
/run/user/<user id(1000)>/gvfs
```

But these are the current mount locations

```
~/.gvfs/
```

or

```
/run/user/$USERNAME/gvfs
```

or

```
$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the desktop or program you use (gnome,kde,smb4k..) it might be in one place or another. It might also have a session id in the path, However, all is reported by the `mount` command. Open the remote folder, and then in terminal type `mount` and enter. Mount will list all that is mounted and where is mounted.

If you want to ensure that your path is always mounted/ automounted on login in your desired directory, then your command line is the safest bet.

Potentially you could mount it on command line as well in the desired folder:

```
mount -t cifs //server-name/share-name /mnt/<share_folder> -o username=shareuser,password=sharepassword,domain=nixcraft
```

And go further than this and add it in fstab, thus when your computer boots, share is mounted on startup:

```
//server-name/share-name     /mnt/<share_folder>     cifs   defaults,username=shareuser,password=sharepassword,domain=nixcraft     0     0
```

Comment: This doenst answer this question my friend

Comment: I've updated the answer.