# Location of "Connect to Server" mount in a guest session

Tags: 14.04, mount, nautilus

The question where to find the mount point when connecting to a server through *Files* has been asked and answered before [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/q/50004/178369). However, when logged into a **guest session**, none of the suggested paths allow me to access the mounted files:

```
$ ls -al ~/.gvfs
ls: cannot access /tmp/guest-vK1Glt/.gvfs: No such file or directory

$ ls -al /run/user/*/gvfs
total 0
drwx------ 2 guest-vK1Glt guest-vK1Glt  40 May 13 09:55 .
drwx------ 9 guest-vK1Glt guest-vK1Glt 240 May 13 09:55 ..

$ ls -al $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs 
total 0
drwx------ 2 guest-vK1Glt guest-vK1Glt  40 May 13 09:55 .
drwx------ 9 guest-vK1Glt guest-vK1Glt 240 May 13 09:55 ..
```

(Note that the last two are actually the same in my case.)

Any ideas where I can find the actual path to the mounted directory?

I can access the files without problems within *Files*, so I know that the mount succeeded.